# Computer doesn't boot - with fast startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-10, multi-boot

A computer with Windows 10 with "fast startup" can’t boot - the drive is turning, but the display remains dark.

I tried booting from a system repair disk, but it doesn't change anything - it doesn't even start booting from it, probably because the computer never "boots", it just *resumes* from hibernation. Pressing ESC doesn't help (I never get the message to press it, either).

**The *only* thing that can be done with it is**: Press the power button for 10 seconds to turn it off, and press it again to turn it "on".

More information: It's a dual boot system with Windows 7 on the other partition.

Any solution for this?

Comment: This behavior always happens or only when a specific boot order happens, Windows 10 by default, uses a hybrid-shutdown.  Which installation was installed first?

Comment: Maybe this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987722/disabling-fast-startup-in-windows-8-thru-programming - you have to edit Windows 10 registry from Windows 7.

Comment: @snayob Thanks. But as I said, It can't boot at all.

Comment: You can edit registry using system repair disk. Change boot order of devices, put DVD or USB as first boot device in firmware.